# Switch with VLANs and non-VLAN ports?

Tags: vlan, hp, networking

I have a HP 1920S switch with several VLANs configured. Is it possible to use the remaining ports as ordinary (no VLAN at all) 'dumb' switch ports?

The reason I ask is that I have devices that don't play nicely with VLANs, but work absolutely fine when connected to a plain old unmanaged switch, but this leads to a messy 2 switch solution when I'd rather just have one.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

All ports of any VLAN-capable switchs are always in a VLAN.

Generally by default, and/or it there's no specific configuration on the port it is in VLAN 1

But you may want to further diagnose the issue. If a port is correctly configured as access for a VLAN, for the device connected on this port there's absolutely no difference with an unmanaged switch.

You should edit your question to add the switch configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you use edge (=device uplink) ports untagged with the VLAN they should belong to.

Tagged VLAN ports (trunks) are normally only used between VLAN-capable switches and those servers that need access to multiple VLANs.

Using tags on edge ports can be cumbersome and may become a security problem ("VLAN hopping") when you base security on VLANs and don't make sure that (tagged or untagged) VLAN membership is restricted as required by your zoning.